# Styling divs with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I need help aligning my divs acording to example below:

[image]

What I got so far is this:

[image]

I cant apply spacing in between the two divs, and the divs are not the same height.

My Html:

```
            <div class="container - fluid">
                    <div class="row" id="wrapper">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8" id="columneone"> 
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4" id="columnetwo">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My css(I am using less):

```
#columneone{background-color:@deepblue !important; color:white !important;}
#columnetwo{background-color:@lightblue !important; color:white !important; }
#wrapper{margin-right:-173px; margin-left:-173px; padding-top: 10px}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should review Bootstrap's documentation about its Grid as it will provide you with a better understanding for why your initial attempt lacked gutters between the background colors, as well as a variety of other ways you could improve your previous attempt.

In Bootstrap 4 we can take advantage of a host of new utility classes as well as the flexbox grid to achieve your desired results.

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
  
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="bg-dark h-100 p-3">
        <p class="text-white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="bg-secondary h-100 p-3">
        <p class="text-white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

The colors used here are just pulled using Bootstraps `.bg-*` utility classes, you'll need to adjust that to correctly reflect your preferred scheme.

Comment: Unfortunately Bootstrap 4 seems not be able to work properly with Grunt , therefore I cannot use bootstrap 4, I use 3.3.7 . Can you help me with this version of Bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 has no native support for flexbox, so you would either need to create those classes necessary or rely on JavaScript.